# How to codecov properly a code that is expanded by a macro

Tags: c, macros, code-coverage, codecov

I'm having some trouble on trying to check the code coverage of one of my projects on github hosted [here](https://github.com/LeoVen/C-Macro-Collections). It is mainly C and macros that expand to some usable code.

I was writing one test and decided to publish it earlier. This means that the test was not completely testing all the functionalities that were expanded by the macro, but somehow got a 100% code coverage for that specific file. All tests passed (so all non-generated code got through) but not all functions that were expanded by the macro, so I assumed that the code generated was not being taken into account.

So I saw two possibilities:

- A - **Do some compiler trick so that codecov can take the expanded code into account**;
- B - Copy and paste the resulting macro into the file directly (which is not ideal, since the macro expansion could change).

[image: code_image]

`CMC_CREATE_UNIT` is expanded into a single function that is then called into main down below (not shown). `CMC_CREATE_TEST` expands into a series of `do {} while(0)` (more details [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222954/simple-unit-test-in-c)). Also `LIST_GENERATE` expands into a series of functions that are the target of this unit test.

Comment: I dont know much about codecov but gcov does not take into account the macro expansion and so they recommend that macro functions be changed to inlines and avoid multi-line definitions as they would ultimately be treated as one line during final stats. If you want you may generate the preprocessed code with '-E' flag in GCC and then run codecov on the preprocessed code.

Comment: If the code coverage counts lines covered, then macros end up as one line in the program processed by the compiler proper, so if that line is a function definition, any call into that function ends up being treated as 'all the code in the function is executed'.  It isn't easy to finagle your way around 'preprocessor expands macros into single lines'.